# Does adding DC/DC converter output filter affect EMI filtering?

Tags: power, analog, dc-dc-converter, filter

I want to use a 1"x1" brick DC/DC converter (Exact P#:[SKMW06G-05](https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/dc-dc-converter-pcb-mount-ultrawide-input-18-75vdc-skmw06g--05)) to power multiple circuits.

One of the loads is analog circuit which is sensitive to noise, so I would like to apply further filtering to this branch which consumes maximum of 200mA.

**Specifications:**

- The converter switching frequency is 300kHz
- Ripple is 85mVpp
- Maximum output capacitor is 1000uF

The recommended circuit to meet EMC (and I think to guarantee the noise levels they mention in datasheet) is shown below:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. Can I increase C4 to the maximum value (1000uF) without affecting any other component?
2. For the noise sensitive circuit is it safe to add after C4 a damped RLC filter shown below without hurting output and loop stability of the converter?

[image]

3. Does this filter have any effect on the EMC filter?
4. This filter would reduce differential mode noise and output ripple only, correct? What about common mode noise? Do I need a second stage with CM choke? I have read that usually CM noise is not an issue and is not addressed in such applications.

Comment: The usual solution to sensitive analog circuitry is to use a LDO (Low DropOut) linear regulator.  Adding LC components after a DC-DC can cause unintended oscillation or instability.

Comment: I thought the adding R to the LC will remove oscillations ?

Comment: @rdtsc , I didnot say adding inductance to 1000uF capacitor. What i Said in the question is adding RLC filter (near load) after the 1000uF (which is close to the converter) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I increase C4 to the maximum value (1000uF) without affecting any
> other component ?

If the load is purely resistive, then yes. If there is additional capacitance in the load, then C4 will need to be derated to include that capacitance. (like if the load has 500uF, 500uF would be sufficient for C4. Capacitance can be buffered by resistors and inductors. The main problems are what the switcher 'sees' as a capacitive load and inrush current. If the inrush current is too high it may see the load as a short and not turn on if the switcher has overcurrent protection.

> For the noise sensitive circuit is it safe to add after C4 a Damped
> RLC filter shown below without hurting output and loop stability of
> the converter ?

It would be better than just adding RC on the output, its hard to say without having the details of the switcher such as output impedance. If you had output impedance with frequency or a bode chart you could find if it affects loop stabilty. An easier way is to add and LDO with a really low voltage drop. LDO's can have voltage drops as low as 0.3V.

> This filter would reduces differential mode noise and output ripple
> only correct ? What about common mode noise , do I need a second stage
> with CM Chock ? I have read that usually CM noise is not an issue and
> is not addressed in such applications.

Low frequency noise is not blocked by the RC, only high frequency noise, that reduces the ripple that the load sees but only in the sense that the high frequency content is reduced. This is also good if you are knocking out the switching frequency, its not good for a sensitive load to see switching, but the load will see the low frequency noise.

Comment: Regarding question 1 : Does this mean that the emc filter is not dependent on C4 value right ?

Comment: What do you mean by dependent, the input capacitors don't 'see'  the output capacitors impedance, there is a switcher inbetween with an active load.